# Updating MatrializeCss select value from KnockoutJs ViewModel

Tags: knockout.js, materialize

i'm using materializecss with knockoutjs to create some forms. It works fine. When I set the value from the ui the knockout view model updates as expected.

The reverse is however not working as expected. Updating the value from knockout does not work. After checking the source on [github](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/js/forms.js), I could only come up with the code below.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.materialSelect = {
    init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext){
        $(element).material_select();
    },
    update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext){
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        if (value){
            var items = $(element).children('option').map(function(x,y){ return $(y).attr('value')}).toArray();
            var index = _.indexOf(items,value);
            if (index!=-1){
                var li = $(element).siblings('ul').children('li').eq(index);
                li.click();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

It works but I do not really like it.
Is there a better way to do this?

This is the html

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select id="item1" class="validate"
        data-bind="optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id',options: store.item1.data, value: model.gender, optionsCaption: 'Select one...', optionsAfterRender: store.item1.setup, materialSelect" >
    </select>
    <label>Gender</label>
</div>
```

The model is a normal javascript object with ko.track called on it. Eg

`var model = ko.track({ gender: undefined });`

Comment: Also show the HTML with the binding, and the relevant part of the viewmodel.

Comment: @connexo Updates with sample code.